# Use Solve for two Functions to find 1 common Variable

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, variable

I have 2 functions that look like this:

F[t_,d_]:= 10+t+2d

G[t_,d_]:= 5+t+d

I'd like to solve this in such a way to know for which **t both Function have the Same value.**

I assume that this won't be a single solution, rather a table/list full of values for different d's. But I can't get even that.

Thanks in advance for any help (:

Comment: FindInstance[F[t, d] == G[t, d], {t, d}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
F[t_, d_] := 10 + t + 2 d
G[t_, d_] := 5 + t + d

Plot3D[{F[t, d], G[t, d]}, {t, 0, 10}, {d, -10, 5}, 
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {t, d})]
```

[image]

Consequently, the functions are equal for any `t` provided that `d` is

```
Solve[F[t, d] == G[t, d], d][[1]]

(* {d -> -5} *)
```